# Isn't chromatic number just the minimum number of independent sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Almost everywhere I read it defines chromatic number as the smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of G so that no two adjacent vertices share the same color. But if adjacent vertices are of different colours, it seems to mean that adjacent vertices belong to different independent sets. So, I'm almost certain that the definition in title is correct, but I couldn't find a standard source where it is defined like it. So, I'm posting this question to get confirmation.

Comment: At the very least you want to specify that the independent sets cover all the vertices. But other than that it sounds reasonable, at least at first glance.

Comment: You can even restrict to *maximal* independent sets without loss of generality.  Here's a useful reference: https://mat.tepper.cmu.edu/trick/color.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
More specifically, the chromatic number of $G=(V,E)$ is the minimum size of a partition of $V$ such that each part of the partition is an independent set.

Given a partition into $k$ independent sets, you can get a $k$-colouring by colouring all the vertices in part $P_i\subset V$ the colour $i$.

And, given a $k$-colouring $c: V\to \{1,2,\dots, k\}$, the colour classes $c^{-1}(i)$ form a partition of $V$ into $k$ independent sets.